# How many complements are in "I ask you to clean the room"?

Tags: complements

How many complements are needed in the below sentence?

> "I ask you to clean the room."

This sentence above has one complement or two complements?

Answer (score 2):

> How many complements are needed in the below sentence?
>
> - 1. "I ask you to clean the room."

The expected answer might depend on the grammar book you are using or on your teacher.

This is how I would parse something like that:

2. "[I] asked [you] [to clean the room]."

The parts of that sentence #2, at matrix clause level, are:

- "**asked"**: the matrix verb of the sentence.
- "**I**": a complement. It is functioning as the *subject*, and the subject is an external complement.
- "**you**": a complement. It is an internal complement. It is functioning as an *object* (though some linguists might disagree here on this point).
- "**to clean the room**": a complement. It is an internal complement. It is a *to*-infinitival clause.

And so, my answer would be: There are three complements.

CAVEAT: Your teacher and/or grammar textbook might want a different answer from what I had just given you.